# Java generics type variable as array type

Tags: java, generics

While learning Java Generics, I found this statement in [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) :

> A type variable can be any non-primitive type you specify: any class
>   type, any interface type, any array type, or even another type
>   variable.

By `array type` did they mean primitive array or ArrayList ? If they mean primitive array , how should we code it ?

Comment: Any type of array can be used as a generic type parameter, e.g., `List<byte[]>` or `Collection<String[]>`.

Comment: By "any array type" they meant any array type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
public class Test {
    static void main(String[] asdf) {
        Asdf<int[]> obj = new Asdf<int[]>();
        obj.foo();
    }
}
class Asdf<T> {
    public void foo() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has a class for every array type, so there's a class for int[], there's a class for Test[]. These classes are created by JVM.

You can access them as

```
int[].class
Test[].class.
```